# Install PECL modules without the prompts

Tags: php, pecl

I just installed PHP on Ubuntu Natty from source.

I'm trying to use PECL to install additional modules like APC and Memcache. I'm using something like this:

```
pecl install apc
```

However, I get prompts asking me to confirm things.

How can I use the pecl command to just accept the defaults? I saw something like this on a message board: `printf "yes\n" | pecl install pecl_http`. However, in the case of APC this would answer yes for things where the default is no (I think).

Comment: @Gordon: I tried that but there doesn't seem to be a handle for what I need.

Comment: For the case where the default values are acceptable, in non interactive mode, PECL prompt is not required. For example, if you add to a Dockefile `RUN pecl install apc`, at build time, you'll get the default values automatically selected.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

The following code seems to work ok:

```
printf "\n" | pecl install apc
```

You can also replace apc with any other PECL package.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm also seeing success with `yes | pecl install memcache` -- although I suppose your solution works better for packages where the default is something other than "yes"

Comment: Thanks dude, this even worked with [CircleCI](https://circleci.com/docs/language-php)

Comment: Worked for me since I'm installing the extension in a docker container! Thanks!

Answer (score 96):

The "yes" command can do more than just type "yes"; it can type anything you want, over and over. Including an empty line, which is a good way to accept defaults.

I just needed this myself, so here is what worked well for me:

```
yes '' | pecl install -f apc
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, Tom. Was your code meant to be `"yes\n" | pecl install -f apc`?!

Comment: @ObinwanneHill: Tom was referring to the [`yes`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/yes) command. The benefit of this over `printf` is that it generates output repeatedly, which makes it more portable should the pecl installer prompt for additional questions than your scripted `printf` expected.

Comment: @jmikola Oh I see, was not familiar with that command. Thanks

Comment: The problem comes when you want a NO instead of a YES in any of the options

Answer (score 21):

If you don't want give the same answer for every single prompt ("yes", "no", or ""), you can use `--configureoptions` to set specific values for each option (see the [PECL manual](https://pear.php.net/manual/en/guide.developers.package2.pecl.php)).

You'll want to find your package's package.xml file to see what options are configurable. As an example, for the `memcached` package, you'd go here:

https://github.com/php-memcached-dev/php-memcached/blob/master/package.xml

Search for the `<configureoption>` tags, which in this case are:

```xml
<configureoption name="with-libmemcached-dir"     prompt="libmemcached directory"     default="no"/>
<configureoption name="with-zlib-dir"             prompt="zlib directory"             default="no"/>
<configureoption name="with-system-fastlz"        prompt="use system fastlz"          default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-igbinary" prompt="enable igbinary serializer" default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-msgpack"  prompt="enable msgpack serializer"  default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-json"     prompt="enable json serializer"     default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-protocol" prompt="enable server protocol"     default="no"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-sasl"     prompt="enable sasl"                default="yes"/>
<configureoption name="enable-memcached-session"  prompt="enable sessions"            default="yes"/>
```

You can then pass these options along to the install command like so:

```bash
pecl install --configureoptions 'with-libmemcached-dir="no" with-zlib-dir="no" with-system-fastlz="no" enable-memcached-igbinary="yes" enable-memcached-msgpack="no" enable-memcached-json="no" enable-memcached-protocol="no" enable-memcached-sasl="yes" enable-memcached-session="yes"' memcached
```

Answer (score 9):

Obinwanne's Hill answer nailed it for me, so I'm not providing anything new here, but the following seems like the absolute shortest also without any fancy tools.

```
echo '' | pecl install apc
```

Comment: A shorter alternative to achieve the same result is: `pecl install apc <<<''`

Comment: You can go even shorter `echo | pecl install apc`, without the ''. Cheers!!