# pecl install - how to specify options?

Tags: php, pecl

I'm trying to install `event` extension for PHP using pecl. During the installation I get several prompts:

```
Enable internal debugging in Event [no] : 
Enable sockets support in Event [yes] : 
libevent installation prefix [/usr] : 
Include libevent's pthreads library and enable thread safety support in Event [no] : 
Include libevent protocol-specific functionality support including HTTP, DNS, and RPC [yes] : 
Include libevent OpenSSL support [yes] : 
PHP Namespace for all Event classes [no] : 
openssl installation prefix [no] :
```

But ofc that only happens in the interactive mode. I need to do this without interaction, for instance in Dockerfile. The default values don't work for me so I need to change them with command line options. How?

Keep in mind that I need to answer differently for each question so `yes '' | pecl install ...` doesn't work at all. Also one of the questions needs a path and not yes/no.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Install PECL modules without the prompts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141407/install-pecl-modules-without-the-prompts)

Comment: Not at all, I found that already.

Comment: Pinging OP @enumag - have you found a satisfactory solution?

Comment: @SzczepanHołyszewski I did not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's now possible to pass configuration options to `pecl install` via `--configureoptions`.

You'll want to find your package's package.xml file to see what options are configurable. For the `event` package, you'll go here:

https://bitbucket.org/osmanov/pecl-event/src/master/package.xml

Search for the `<configureoption>` tags, which in this case are:

```xml
<configureoption default="no" name="enable-event-debug" prompt="Enable internal debugging in Event"/>
<configureoption default="yes" name="enable-event-sockets" prompt="Enable sockets support in Event"/>
<configureoption default="/usr" name="with-event-libevent-dir" prompt="libevent installation prefix"/>
<configureoption default="no" name="with-event-pthreads" prompt="Include libevent's pthreads library and enable thread safety support in Event"/>
<configureoption default="yes" name="with-event-extra" prompt="Include libevent protocol-specific functionality support including HTTP, DNS, and RPC"/>
<configureoption default="yes" name="with-event-openssl" prompt="Include libevent OpenSSL support"/>
<configureoption default="no" name="with-event-ns" prompt="PHP Namespace for all Event classes"/>
<configureoption default="yes" name="with-openssl-dir" prompt="openssl installation prefix"/>
```

You can then pass these options along to the install command like so:

```bash
pecl install --configureoptions 'enable-event-debug="no" with-event-libevent-dir="/my/dir" with-event-ns="yes"' event
```

Comment: Nice! What version of PHP / Pecl implements this?

Comment: @enumag It looks like it's been there since Nov 2019 / v.1.10.10: https://github.com/pear/pear-core/pull/90, https://github.com/pear/pear-core/commit/0b379be82b165d4f37b12d7e63c658ba620861e4

Comment: is same: pecl install -D ...

Answer (score 1):

Non-interactive mode for pecl is not yet available. It can be supplemented with `yes` command. Command outputs affirmatives until terminated.

You may use `yes` with pipe like this: `yes '' | pecl install ...`

Edit: If you are not in need output yes every iteration, just echo your answers like `echo 'yes\n no\n ...' | pecl install ...`

More edit: If you are using this solution in docker, in Dockerfile you may use command `docker-php-ext-install event` and then `docker-php-ext-configure ...`

Comment: I don't want to answer yes to all prompts though. I need to answer differently for different question. Also one prompt asks for a path.

Comment: well, at first I must not recommend pecl at all - you should use modern library for loop events. You may choose here: https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php#event

Comment: And I updated answet to be more flexibe to your needs

Comment: All event loop libraries require or at least heavily recommend using some PHP extension for better performance - usually ev, event or uv. How do I install any of these extensions without pecl? For the record I'm using the Amp library (fist one listed on the list you linked).

Comment: Btw using `echo 'answers' | pecl install...` won't work because the prompts don't happen at all in non-interactive mode. Is there a way to force the prompts to appear anyway so that I can use your way?

Comment: In dockerfile (as you stated) you can use interactive mode - fe. command `echo 'no\n' | pecl install ...` will work. Scripted does not mean non-interactive mode

Comment: @enumag I added solution specifically for docker, check it out

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I don't know why. `php -r "var_dump(extension_loaded('event'));"` returns true. But `docker-php-ext-configure event --with-event-openssl=no` fails with https://gist.github.com/enumag/fccf3d7182b421c4226d85af68b2bc9e

Comment: As for `docker-php-ext-install event`, that also fails with similar error. Apparently this command doesn't at all for pecl extensions.

Comment: I tried your `echo 'yes\n no\n ...' | pecl install ...` trick but it doesn't work either - the extension is still installed with the default values instead of what I specified in the echo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHP [workerman](https://github.com/walkor/workerman) these days and also meet this problem when install `event` extension in Docker. Following workerman's documents, `event` should be configured as:

- do NOT include libevent OpenSSL support
- ENABLE PHP Namespace for all Event classes

which means one should type `no` for interactive question `Include libevent OpenSSL support [yes] :` and `yes` for `Include libevent OpenSSL support [yes] :`, while just leave `enter` for other questions.

You may try **THIS** solution (and also put `RUN` in the head in `Dockerfile`):

```
printf "\n\n\n\n\nno\nyes\n\n" | pecl install event
```

`echo '\n\n\n\n\nno\nyes\n\n'` do NOT work since it seems not be used as interactive answers, which sends whole string as the configuration parameter value, and you may see this:

```
running: /tmp/pear/temp/event/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --enable-event-debug=\n\n\n\n\nno\nyes\n\n ...
```